# Formula field implementation: Check if 'Field A' OR 'Field B' contains text "Spring" in the first word

Tags: salesforce, crm, salesforce-lightning, salesforce-communities

I need your help. I implemented a formula checkbox to check if Field A contains a text 'Spring':

Solution: `If(CONTAINS(Field_A__c,"Spring"),true,false)`

but then a condition got added to check if Field A contains first word as "Spring"

Solution: Formula text field -> `LEFT(Field_A__c, FIND(" ", Field_A__c) -1)`

Now, again the condition added to check if 'Field A' OR 'Field B' contains text "Spring" in the first word (Field A or Field B can have just one or two words separated by space). Can you help me resolve this through a formula field? Thanks!

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you stuck? The `OR()` function will help you here.

Comment: OR() function helped!